# Nativescript Android - hide keyboard

Tags: nativescript

In my Nativescript app, the application starts with the login page.  On iOS everything looks good, but on android, the username field is focused and the keyboard is showing. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

So far I have tried:

- Getting a reference of another element (a label) and calling lbl.focus() in the page's onLoaded event
- getting a reference of the username textfield and calling txt.dismissSoftInput() and txt.android.clearFocus()

None of this worked.  Is there another way to hide the keyboard when the page is loaded?

Thank you

Comment: There is an open issue -https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2432  with similar problem in GitHub with possible workaround. You could also review the attached sample project in the repo.

Comment: I have been trying to use this code, but in my case it is not working.  I am not sure why.  Any ideas?

Comment: I reviewed you scenario and tested it in a local project, however `.clearFocus()` works for me. It would help if you could give some more info about your problem or if you could send me sample project, which could be debugged locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up implementing a different solution.  This may not be the best approach, but it serves its purpose in my case and I wanted to share it for those of you that face a similar scenario.

in page's loaded event I included this code:

```js
    if (page.android) {
        var un = page.getViewById('username');
        var p = page.getViewById('password');
        un.android.setFocusable(false);
        p.android.setFocusable(false);
        setTimeout(function () {
            un.android.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            p.android.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }, 300);
    }
```

The key here is the setTimeout function (Thanks Emil Oberg for pointing me to the right direction).  As far as I understand, here is what is happening:

- The page loads and we call setFocusable(false) on the only 2 text fields to prevent Android from setting the focus on them
- Then we wait 300ms to allow Android to do its initialization
- When the timeout executes, call setFocusableInTouchMode(true) to allow the fields to gain focus.

At this point the page is loaded without any fields to be in focus and with the keyboard hidden. If the user taps any of the fields the keyboard will appear and they can proceed to log in as usual.

As I mentioned, this may not be the best, or correct, approach, but works for me.  Hope this can save someone the time to research the issue.

Comment: This seems like the only legit way to do it right now. sigh. Thanks for the snippet, gona use it!

Comment: Working with {N} version 3.0.0. Seems to be the only way until now. However, I had to use @ViewChild("email") inputFldEmail: ElementRef; to get the view.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the username field is either textview or textfield. If so, try this on `loaded` callback:

```
var myTextview = page.getViewById("myTextView");
myTextView.dismissSoftInput();
```

Comment: Thank you Dinh,  I tried that but for some reason it is not working.  Are there any other conditions that need to be met for this to work?

Comment: This is just a method of textview or textfield from NativeScript API so it should work normally. I will make a test asap.

Comment: Dihn,  I ended up using a different approach.  See my answer for details.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You want to clear the focus of the field in the `loaded` callback:

```
var searchBar = page.getViewById('my-search-bar-id');
if (searchBar.android) {
    searchBar.android.clearFocus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emil.  I tried:
    var un = page.getViewById('username');
    if (un.android) {
        un.android.clearFocus();
    }
but it does not work.  The field is still selected and the keyboard is active

Comment: And you've an input with the id `username` I assume. Take a look at this code I wrote a few months back: https://github.com/emiloberg/oppna-program-reklistan-app/blob/d1bfcc6c0c5da28d50622c75dc210bd61db54d1a/src/app/views/search.js#L100-L106

Comment: yes, you are correct, 'username' is the id of the textfield.  Your code suggestion should be working, but for some reason it is not.  There must be something else going on.

Comment: For debugging purposes, try wrapping it in a `setTimeout()`. Also note that "Note: When a View clears focus the framework is trying to give focus to the first focusable View from the top. Hence, if this View is the first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks related to clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will give focus to this view." ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html )

Comment: Good tip,  the setTimeout() helped.  The frameworks set the focus and then the code removes it.  Still not ideal because the keyboard is shown for a fraction of the second, but at the least it hides after that.

Comment: You can also try setting the focus to another view (which does not spawn a keyboard). e.g. `notSearchBar.android.requestFocus()`

Comment: `clearFocus()` worked for me on a search bar that was in a separate view (tab) and was activating the keyboard when the view first loaded

Answer (score 0):

What about combining both tips above?

```
onClear(args) {
      const searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
      if (isAndroid && searchBar.android != undefined){//avoid random unpleasant error
         setTimeout(() => { // the key here was this timeout
            searchBar.android.clearFocus();
      }, 1)
   }
}
```